# Turning Html.ValidationSummary into a javascript friendly string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, toastr

I have a partial view that is being called via `Ajax.BeginForm()` and I need to return the `Html.ValidationSummary()` in a script tag that will show up with toastr

Here's the code I have in partial:

```
<script id="partial-js-container" data-ajax-update="true">
    toastr.error('@Html.ValidationSummary()');
</script>
```

The string that's being returned in `Html.ValidationSummary()` has a cariage return in it and ends up not working. How can I fix this and make it robust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix this and make it robust?

By properly encoding it:

```
<script id="partial-js-container" data-ajax-update="true">
     var message = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(((@Html.ValidationSummary()==null)?"":@Html.ValidationSummary().ToHtmlString())));
                if (message.length > 0) {
            toastr.error(message);
        }
</script>
```